# Showing and hiding dynamically generated ID's with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The code below is showing and hiding div content with `dynamically generated id's` like `div_1, div_2` from `div id`, all seems working fine except that it requires to hide one div content at a time like clicking div_1 should open its content and on clicking div_2 should hide div_1. please help me sort out this problem.

```
echo "<span class='bold'><a name='form_a_$group_seq' href='#div_$group_seq' id='form_a_$group_seq' value='1' " .
"onclick='return divclick(this,\"div_$group_seq\");'";
 if ($display_style == 'block') echo "clicked";
 echo "<b>" . xl_layout_label($group_name) . "</b></a></span>\n";

 echo "<div id='div_$group_seq' class='section' style='display:$display_style;'>\n";
 echo " <table border='0' cellpadding='0'>\n";
 $display_style = 'none';
}
else if (strlen($last_group) == 0) {
echo " <table border='0' cellpadding='0'>\n";
}
```

Below is the javascript to make the code workable. but its showing or hiding all the div contents at a time.

```
function divclick(a, divid) {
    var divstyle = document.getElementById(divid).style;
    if ( divstyle.display == 'none' ) {
        divstyle.display = 'block';
    } else {
        divstyle.display = 'none';
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is a piece of updated html code that's what browser is rendering.

```
<div class='container2'><ul class='taby'><li class='dropown'><a name='form_a_1' href='#div_1'   id='form_a_1' value='1' onclick='return divclick(this,"div_1");'>Who</a></li></ul>
<div id='div_1' class='section'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0'>
<div id='div_2' class='section'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0'>
<div id='div_3' class='section'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0'>
```

Comment: You should provide rendered HTML instead of PHP code.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Please post an example of the rendered HTML.

Comment: HTML is getting rendered from php file should i post this PHP file?

Comment: Yes, we understand how PHP works and no, you don't need to post the PHP. Post the rendered HTML.

Comment: No, you should post what browser "sees".

Comment: you should look into `jQuery` or another js library as it would make this much more trivial then what you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery in the page you can add one line in your code

```
function divclick(a, divid) {
    var divstyle = document.getElementById(divid).style;
    if ( divstyle.display == 'none' ) {
        $(".section").css('display', 'none');
        divstyle.display = 'block';
    } else {
        divstyle.display = 'none';
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you are not using jquery on the page it gets a little more complicated but can be done with only adding a few lines.

```
function divclick(a, divid) {
    var divstyle = document.getElementById(divid).style;
    if ( divstyle.display == 'none' ) {
        var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(sections, function(section){
            section.style.display = 'none';
        });
        divstyle.display = 'block';
    } else {
        divstyle.display = 'none';
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: its not working, clicking the button is showing the content without hiding the previous opened content..which is so messy.

Comment: I wanna thank you again, i was struggling for this solution for the past three days.

Answer (score 1):

This is really too messy to work with and understand. You should consider cleaning up the way you dynamically render html, and it would make problems like this a lot easier to solve when you ran into them. Or prevent them all together.

```
<span class='bold' style='background:#0DCAD1'>


<a name="<?php echo "form_a_$group_seq";?>" href="<?php echo "#div_$group_seq";?>" id="<?php echo "form_a_$group_seq";?>" value='1'>
```

etc....

If you render all of your html in echo strings, you'll find it very hard to deal with later on. Especially, when you're working on applications which large amounts of rendering.

Comment: i agree with you but this application has been made in all php. i am still learning the things and trying to customize its UI to the extent i can while learning.